# Watir-webdriver : text.include?("expected text") doesn't work in chrome browser

Tags: ruby, google-chrome, watir, selenium-webdriver, watir-webdriver

I use watir-webdriver for testing in Mac OS. As it is all to known that $browser.text.include?("expected text") is used to assert the text in the screen.
Currently this method works fine in Firefox and htmlunit, but will be fail in Chrome browser. Get the following error in the terminal windows.

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnhandledError: 
    /Users/Zhong/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@ruby192/gems/selenium-webdriver-0.2.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:45:in `assert_ok'
    /Users/Zhong/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@ruby192/gems/selenium-webdriver-0.2.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:15:in `initialize'
    /Users/Zhong/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@ruby192/gems/selenium-webdriver-0.2.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:59:in `new'
    /Users/Zhong/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@ruby192/gems/selenium-webdriver-0.2.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:59:in `create_response'
    /Users/Zhong/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@ruby192/gems/selenium-webdriver-0.2.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:56:in `request'
    /Users/Zhong/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@ruby192/gems/selenium-webdriver-0.2.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:40:in `call'
    /Users/Zhong/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@ruby192/gems/selenium-webdriver-0.2.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:476:in `raw_execute'
    /Users/Zhong/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@ruby192/gems/selenium-webdriver-0.2.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:454:in `execute'
    /Users/Zhong/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@ruby192/gems/selenium-webdriver-0.2.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:348:in `getElementText'
    /Users/Zhong/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@ruby192/gems/selenium-webdriver-0.2.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/element.rb:97:in `text'
    /Users/Zhong/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@ruby192/gems/watir-webdriver-0.2.4/lib/watir-webdriver/browser.rb:95:in `text'
```

Any idea of this? or is it a bug?

Thanks!

Comment: Any chance you can include the code you are trying to execute in addition to the error you are getting? 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bug in the Chrome driver with Chrome 14. Downgrade to Chrome 12-13 and you should be fine.